# Textbook on molecular basis of memory

Tags: neuroscience, book-recommendation

Looking at the rules in the meta, it seems book-recs are a little on the iffy side for on-topic so I hope this is okay.

I am looking for a (graduate-level) textbook that has a thorough treatment of the molecular basis of learning and memory. The issue I am having is that a lot of textbooks seem to cover bits and pieces or just focus on one area. Usually, they just have a few small sections on the molecular events and the rest of the textbook covers channel properties, pharmacology, systems neuro, and behavior.

- [Synapses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004L2KP58) - This one comes close but is now quite dated (2003)
- [The Neurobiology of Learning and Memory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1605352306) - A significant section on the molecular aspect but is not particularly detailed. Very basic idea.

Review articles tend to be difficult because they are more specialized for specific kinases (mTOR, CaMKII etc), events, or channels.

I am trying to get a sense of the broader picture of the just the molecular side of all of this. Specifically the molecular and cell biology that underlies:

- Early-phase LTP (receptor trafficking, signaling pathways)
- Proteins expressed from local translation in dendritic spines, signaling pathways that control this
- Details on synaptic tagging hypothesis
- Late-phase LTP events, pathways, proteins, and regulation
- Downstream effects of activation of different channels, how they control pathways below, how they all intersect and how this differs by brain area and cell type
- LTD events
- Events at the post-synaptic density (receptors, ion-channels, protein composition, scaffolding, actin network)
- Synaptogenesis, plasticity, maintenance during long-term memory
- Kinases in learning and memory
- Transcriptional control
- Post-translational modifications and consequences for learning and memory
- Scaffolding proteins and their contribution to signal stability
- Pre-synaptic events
- Contributions of glia/auxiliary neuronal cells
- Bonus: Disease focus - what pathways and proteins underlie various well-studied genetic diseases?
- etc.

I know this is a tall order but with 1000+ page textbooks out there on other neuroscience topics, surely someone has written something? Review article are great too, perhaps I just haven't found the right one yet.

Comment: From what I am aware of, most of the molecular basis of memory research is relatively new, and thus will likely only be in primary literature at this point, there is usually a 5 to 10 year lag for the most recent research to make it into the textbooks. There is the [Cognitive Sciences Stack](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com), where you might have a more focused audience for your question. @AliceD may have some advice on this topic though, or at least where to start looking for good reviews. The journal Neuron comes to mind, but I am not sure if there would be more specialized journals.